# How to search nested Doc in Elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have multiple indices on of them called Post with Nested document Comment.

this is how my documents defined

```
class CommentDoc(InnerDoc):
    title = Text(analyzer=ngram_analyzer)
    content = Text(analyzer=ngram_analyzer)
class PostDoc(Document):
    content = Text(analyzer=ngram_analyzer)
    comments = Nested(Icd10Doc)
    id = Integer()
```

this is how I'm doing the current search

```
s = Search(index=['post', 'blog', 'artical'])
q = Q("multi_match", query="whatever", fields=['name', 'title', 'content'])
s = s.query(q)
```

So how can I search the Post index using the nested Docs inside comments?

what should I add to fields array?

Answer (score 0):

At first I think you should edit your models but I'm not sure:

```
comments = Nested(Icd10Doc) ---> comments = Nested(CommentDoc)
```

I had tested this query at similiar conditions and I think its works for you

```
nested_q = Q("nested", path='comments', query=Q("multi_match", query="whatever", fields=['comments.content']))
```

And finally if you want to combine queries you can use this:

```
final_q = nested_q & other_q (for AND operation)

final_q = nested_q | other_q (for OR operation)
```

And finally:

```
s = s.query(final_q)
```